# angular typeahead/autocomplete for contenteditable

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

Basically, what my client asked me to do is similar to tag friends in Facebook/youtube comment.

1. must start with @
2. a popup suggesting a list, upon selected, the value is appended back to the original contenteditable

I have tried 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
and ngTagsInput , they are close but not enough... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet this is what you are looking for http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-mention/example/ . I have to admit it took me quite a few days to find it (via google)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You're building autocomplete for tags.  If you plan to reuse it, then you'll need to write a custom directive.  If not, then you can do a messy implementation inside of your controller.

You'll need the html element you are editing to look like this:

```
<div ng-model="newtag" ng-change="tagchanged()" ng-bind="newtag"></div>
```

ng-change will fire on change, so your function will need to have a debounce (wait a period of time) in order to wait until the user finishes typing.  You can accomplish this with a setTimeout of 500ms.  If it changes during that time period, kill the timeout.  But if it doesnt, do your api call to get the list of potential tags and show them in a list below the field.  You'll want the css for the results to let them align to the search field and hover above the rest of your page.